# Parsing the results of askopenfilenames()?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get a list of filenames from tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames() in Python 3.2.

```
    files = askopenfilenames(initialdir="C:\\Users\\BVCAP\\Videos", title="Select files")
    self.num_files.set(len(files))
```

I was expecting the output to be a tuple (or maybe a list) with each element containing a filename. As far as I can tell, it's returning a string with each element contained within curly-brackets {} like so:

`{C:\Users\BVCAP\File1.txt} {C:\Users\BVCAP\File2.txt}`

This is what I get if I try print(files). It looks like it's formatted like a list of some sort, but it seems to just be a string. Am I doing something wrong, or is the output of this function actually a string formatted like a list of files, which I need to split up by myself.

Comment: Eek! What do you get when there's a brace (`{` or `}`) in a filename?

Comment: @Gabe: if that happens I will personally strangle whoever put a curly brace in the file name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually a bug on the Windows version that has been present since around the 2.6 release of Python. You can find the issue [on their tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue5712), and there's a workaround in the comments (I have not personally tried this workaround because I'm on Linux, which returns a proper tuple). I'm not aware of a fix since then, and the issue has not been marked as closed/resolved.

The suggested workaround in the comment is essentially to do this:

```
master = Tk()
files = askopenfilenames(initialdir="C:\\Users\\BVCAP\\Videos", title="Select files")
files = master.tk.splitlist(files) #Possible workaround
self.num_files.set(len(files))
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know. That workaround didn't actually work, but once I knew it was a string with that format it wasn't an issue to turn it into a list. HI used this instead:  

files = re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', files)

Comment: FWIW, the bug's still in Python 2.7.3 and @Paul's workaround using `re` is probably the simplest workaround, although you might want to make it conditional on whether `askopenfilenames()` has returned something other than a `tuple` in case it ever get fixed.

Comment: Another bug is apparently there's a limit on the number of files that can be selected at one time -- which I've verified using Python 2.7.5. See the question [Quantity limitation for dialog window selecting files or for keys in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863290/quantity-limitation-for-dialog-window-selecting-files-or-for-keys-in-a-dictionar).

Comment: This should have been fixed in 2.7.7.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue19020 and https://bugs.python.org/issue5712.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing this method today, `askopenfilenames` returns a tuple of all files chosen, not the strange string with curly braces anymore (must have been fixed).

Oddly, if the cancel button is pressed or the user exits out of the browse window, an empty string is returned instead of an empty list or tuple. Luckily for us Python recognizes strings as iterable objects, meaning you can still check if `len(filedialog.askopenfilenames()) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for you, because I'm still stuck in Python 2.x, but in my world askopenfilenames returns a tuple, so I doubt it would have changed so much going to 3.x. Maybe try casting as a list:

```
filelist = list(files)
```

Or using a list comprehension by iterating over it:

```
filelist = [file for file in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

I support Eldererathis's answer as the best solution I have found for Python versions 2.X (mainly 2.5 and above) versions under Linux, Mac OS X and Windows. When a `tkFileDialog` calls the `askopenfilename(...,multiple=1)` methods with argument `multiple=1`, I could not get it work properly under Windows (Linux and Mac OS X were fine) when a single file was selected (the file is processed as a `'str'` instead of a `'tuple'`).

I tried the `files = re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', files` suggested by Paul in the comments, but it did not change anything. I also tried `files = tuple(files)` and `files = list(files)`, but it is not a viable workaround from what I have seen.

So far, `files = tkRoot.master.splitlist(files)` is what is working under all environments I have tested (Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64, Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question when looking up why I was getting curly brackets instead of a proper list.

Here's my work around:

```
file_list=[]
files = files = askopenfilenames(initialdir="C:\\Users\\BVCAP\\Videos", title="Select files")
for file in files:
    file_list.append(file)
```

I noticed that when I was using the `askopenfilenames` in my method I never looked at the object returned. I had treated it as a tuple and it worked fine. So knowing it could be iterated in a for loop, it made sense to append each item into a new blank list.

I hope this helps anyone else who encounters this bug.