# How can I get number of files uploaded in tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I currently have this tkintr application that would allow you to upload a file or multiple files. I would like to be able to print to the console how many files were selected.

Currently I can only print what the files selected are with `print self.uploadedfilenames`

I tried to do `len(self.uploadedfilenames)` but I got a number of 52 for one file which I do not understand what it is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox



class Application(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
        options['parent'] = master
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'



        #UPLOAD SECTION
        Label(frame, text='Upload: ').grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.upload = Button(frame, text = "Browse", command = self.askopenfile, width = 10).grid(row=1, column=2)


    def askopenfile(self):
         self.uploadedfilenames = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(multiple=True)
         if self.uploadedfilenames == '':
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="No file was selected")
            return
         else:
             print len(self.uploadedfilenames)

root = Tk()
root.title('application')
_ = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to find out how many files there is ?

Comment: For me it works perfectly as you would expect using `len`. Are you sure you are not doing something weird?

Comment: it is giving me a number such as(54, 71, etc..). However that is not the number of files selected @Axl

Comment: Please, show us exactly the code you are using to do it, because this is not the code you are using.

Comment: @Axl please check my edit

Comment: For me it works. I am almost sure you are doing something weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length you see is because it does not return a tuple as expected, but returns a string instead. This is due to a Windows error.

When I test your code on my PC everything is fine.
Please have a look here:

[Parsing the results of askopenfilenames()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116249/parsing-the-results-of-askopenfilenames)

Also, when you have issues like this, simply print

```
self.uploadedfilenames
```

Then you can see what is returned. That would have helped you out I think.

Comment: `print self.uploadedfilenames` prints the paths of the files selected
is there a way to fix that windows error ?

Comment: If the function returns a string with the file names, like the example I linked to, you you simply extract the file names from the string. This can be done using the .split() method or using regex or what ever you prefer.