# "No such file or directory" when opening file from tkFileDialog.askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to have the user select images to have the logo image pasted onto. The file dialog pops up and lets you choose the image files fine. The logo image also loads up and gets resized. And the New Image file is made.

My problem comes with opening the images that were selected. When it gets to "im = PIL.Image.open(img)" it gives me an IOError that says "No such file or directory".

```
import PIL
import os.path  
import PIL.Image  
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

def logo():

    imgs = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose files', multiple = True)
    logo = PIL.Image.open('logo.jpeg')
    logo_new = logo.resize((125, 100))
    newpath = r'C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\New Images' 
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
    for img in imgs:
        im = PIL.Image.open(img)
        width, height = im.size()
        im.paste(logo_new, ((width-125), (height-100)), mask=logo_new)
        im.save(newpath)

#GUI Code
root = Tk()
root.title("Ad Maker") #GUI title
root.geometry("250x250") #GUI size
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text="Logo", command=logo)
button1.grid() #sets button for the logo function
button2 = Button(app, text = "Frame")
button2.grid() #sets button for the frame function
root.mainloop()
```

I know this code probably isn't the best as I'm still fairly new to programming, but any help in getting the logo() function finally working would be really appreciated.

Comment: What does `print img` do just before the failing line?

Comment: C
:
/
U
s
e
r
s
/
A
u
s
t
i
n
/
D
o
c
u
m
e
n
t
s
/
G
i
t
H
u
b
/
1
.
4
.
7
-
P
r
o
j
e
c
t
/
e
g
a
l
i
t
a
r
i
a
n
i
s
m
.
j
p
e
g

Comment: it prints the location of each of the images that were selected. That was one of them, I hint enter before I finished the comment

Comment: and all the spaces occur verbatim in the output? This seems odd...

Comment: No for some reason it puts every character on a separate line. like C, enter, :, enter, /, enter. Its all written vertically

Comment: This seems to be a bug in tkinter: http://bugs.python.org/issue5712

Comment: Okay then i guess ill have to approach this a different way. Thank you for finding that though i would have never thought that to be a bug

Comment: just to make sure, also do a `print imgs` to check whether it's really a string.

Comment: C:/Users/Austin/Documents/GitHub/1.4.7-Project/egalitarianism.jpeg {C:/Users/Austin/Documents/GitHub/1.4.7-Project/enumerated power.jpeg} C:/Users/Austin/Documents/GitHub/1.4.7-Project/federalism.jpeg
This is the full output when i did print imgs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing the results of askopenfilenames()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116249/parsing-the-results-of-askopenfilenames)

Comment: Okay im getting it to work now with the workaround from that other question. Sorry to repeat a question, thank you so much for your help though

Comment: According to https://bugs.python.org/issue5712, this was fixed in 2.7.7 by the patch for https://bugs.python.org/issue19020.  What version of 2.x are you running?