# how to pass askopenfilename() return value as a parameter to the builtin python function open

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am a new user to Python.

`filename = askopenfilenames()`  This prompts the user to select a file
I want to use `file_selection = open(filename, "r")` with the file selected above.

The issue I am running into is that when you use the `askopenfilenames()` 
(I think) the string is surrounded by `()` therefore the open command doesn't work. Can someone please help me with this?

EDIT:
When I try and replace: filename.replace(",","")
I get error message: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing the results of askopenfilenames()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116249/parsing-the-results-of-askopenfilenames)

Comment: Seems like they didn't really figure anything out

Comment: Can you confirm which operating system and which version of Python please?

Comment: Windows 7 and Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`askopenfilenames()` allows the user to select multiple files; thus it returns a tuple of all the filenames selected.

If you want to allow the user to select multiple files, just iterate over the returned tuple:

```
filenames = askopenfilenames() #filenames is a tuple of strings!
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        #Do stuff with open file f.
```

If you want to allow the user to select only one file, look into `askopenfilename()`.

```
filename = askopenfilename() #filename is a string!
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    #do stuff with open file f
```

Also, there are methods `askopenfile()` and `askopenfiles()` that do the same thing as `askopenfilename()` and `askopenfilenames()` respectively, except instead of returning filenames, they return files open for reading.

```
f = askopenfile() #f is an open file.
#do stuff with f
f.close()
```

and

```
open_files = askopenfiles() #open_files is a tuple of open files.
for f in open_files:
    #do stuff with f
    f.close()
```

Comment: Joe, thank you so much for the information. I am making a GUI and want the user to select 1 or even multiple files. I then want the program to read the file(s) and display the contents of the file (for example company names) and places all of the names from all of the files onto the GUI

Comment: When they select a single file using the askopenfilename() command, and that is saved as a string, do I need to remove anything before entering that variable that is a string into the open command?

Comment: In that case I would use the first or last option. Note, if you use the last option, to get the full name from an open file `f`, use `f.name`. To read an open file, use `f.read()` (returns a string). Perhaps you could use a dictionary; the keys being the filenames and the values being the respective file contents. That's just one way.

Comment: What do you mean by remove anything? `askopenfilename()` should return the full path to that file as a string and can be directly used in the `open` command.

Comment: In option 4 (last option), each time it goes through the for loop will be for a different file...correct?

Comment: I will definitely be accepting this don't worry. askopenfile() works

Comment: I need to figure out the askopenfiles()

Comment: Joe, in askopenfilenames(), do you need to convert to a string before putting it in the open command?

Comment: I forgot to mention - by default `askopenfile()` and `askopenfiles()` returns files in reading mode, but if you want to be explicit, you can set the kwarg `mode` to `"r"`. i.e. `askopenfile(mode="r")` and `askopenfiles(mode="r")`.

Comment: Refer to the first example. `askopenfilenames()` returns a tuple of strings. If you iterate or index into the tuple, you can use the string directly in the open command.

Comment: filename = askopenfilenames()

Comment: for f in filename:
                file_selection = open(f, "r")
                lines = file_selection.read().split()
               
                file_selection.close()