# Tkinter's filedialog.askopenfilenames() returns tuple with curly brackets

Tags: python, tkinter

it returns this

```
{C:/Users/s} {C:/Users/SA} {C:/Users/ls}
```

which I can't do anything with. I have tried to convert it to list.
this old solution (workaround) also doesn't seem to work

```
files = master.tk.splitlist(files) #Possible workaround
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116292/8956217

btw,

```
filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

works ok.

any idea please ? thanks

I have tried to convert it to list.

Comment: In which format do you want the file names?

Comment: Why doesn't the workaround work for you?

Comment: @Dinux just a list without curly brackets

Comment: @TheLizzard it seemingly does nothing, it returns the same result

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Try adding `print(repr(files))` before and after the `files = master.tk.splitlist(files)`. Also check the spelling everywhere. The workaround should always work. Can you give us a [mre]?

Comment: this is my code

`def browsefunc():
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    files = frame.tk.splitlist(files)
    print(files)
    entry.insert(tk.END, files)`


and actually, the frame.tk.splitlist(files) works but only when printed but not when inserted into entry window (still with curly brackets)

Comment: When you try to insert a list into an entry, curly brackets are automatically added because that is how `tcl` converts lists to strings. Try `entry.insert(tk.END, str(files))` instead (converting `files` to a `str`ing before inserting it in the entry).

Comment: @TheLizzard  repr(files)  in entry.insert(tk.END, repr(files)) worked! thanks a lot!